# DJI Mobile SDK for Smart controller and Mavic 2 Pro - no product connection

Tags: dji-sdk

Does Mobile SDK supports Smart controller for Mavic 2?
It looks like no.

App launched on smart controller, registers sdk successfully, but there is no call to `onProductConnect(BaseProduct baseProduct)` 
after 
`DJISDKManager.getInstance().startConnectionToProduct();`

```
'com.dji:dji-sdk:4.9.0.1'
'com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.9'
```

---

29.03.2019

Mavic 2 Pro is listed in supported products.

https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/introduction/product_introduction.html#supported-products

And Mavic 2 Pro can be bought in two combinations. With ordinary controller and smart controller. And i didn't find any information on compatibility with second choice (smart controller). Only information that we can launch third party applications.

Another question is, why USB host port on smart controller is not working when connecting Android device to it. It should work as ordinary controller, but it doesn't.

DJI also doesn't offer ordinary mavic 2 controller as standalone offer. So if you buy Mavic 2 pro with smart controller, it is not possible to control it with Mobile SDK at all, and you can't buy ordinary controller... ((((

P.S. Smart controller - this one:
https://www.dji.com/smart-controller?site=brandsite&from=nav

Answer (score 0):

Which smart controller are you using?

To find which product DJI Mobile SDK supports, you can download the release note from this page: https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/downloads/.

Also, you can check these android tutorial to learn how to connect your app  to DJI Products using DJI Mobile SDK: https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/android-tutorials/index.html

Comment: i've updated original post
Smart controller - this one:
[https://www.dji.com/smart-controller?site=brandsite&from=nav]


i know how to connect. I have completed my application, and it works correctly with Mavic, Spark and Mavic 2 Pro, both by WiFi and with ordinary Spark or Mavic controller, 

But it doesn't work with Mavic 2 Pro  with Smart controller. I tried also all samples, none of them works on Smart controller. 
Hope DJI will correct this in near future, controller is awesome, but doen't work ((